# Problems a Ship May Experience While Attenpting to Survive the Big Bang

Tags: science-fiction

I am currently writing a science fiction short story about a group of humans that have survived until the end of the universe. The main story arc is that they have to instill quantum tunneling in order to start a new Big Bang.

What are some conceivable issues that could cause their ship to be destroyed, or them to be killed?

Comment: It's not obvious if the any of the following concepts are compatible with the hard-science tag: (1) life forms that have survived until the end of universe or anywhere near it (2) something surviving the end of universe (3) end of universe resulting in a new universe (4) quantum tunneling, among all things, being the way to do it; and (5) *instilling* quantum tunneling. I'm not even sure if current hard science is compatible with "the end of the universe", as a continuously expanding universe would never "end", just fade away forever closer and close to zero energy density but not reaching it.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing, not even an atom can survive the Big Bang. There is no space for that, since the expansion of space-time itself started with the Bang. In the first fraction of second, the space was filled up with so much energy that it was not even transparent to light, and any compound particle formed were instantly destroyed.

You could take a look on this page:

https://futurism.com/where-did-the-big-bang-happen-wheres-the-center-of-the-universe/